# Need side content to appear at the bottom in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap for a blog. I need right-side content (social, email signup, etc.) to appear below *all* main blog content in mobile view. It looks how I want on desktop, with the side content appearing to the right of the main content. However, in my current code the side content appears in between two pieces of main content when viewed on mobile.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
        Main content
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push">
        SIDE CONTENT    
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push">
        SIDE CONTENT    
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-push">
        SIDE CONTENT
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Below that I have another container with two rows of main content. I would like the side content to appear below all main content on mobile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using **pull right** simply.

```
<div class="pull-right">SIDE CONTENT</div>
```

[This documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats) might helpful ;-)

Comment: Didn't work. Tried using "pull-right" on its own, it re-sized everything and put it out of order. Keeping my col-lg-4s and adding "pull-right" to the class did not send the side content to the bottom in mobile. It looks the same.